# Subset of a Hilbert scheme consisting of smooth subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebracally closed field $k$.
(In my case $k=\mathbb{C}, X=\mathbb{P}^n$.)

Let us consider the subset of $k$-points of the Hilbert scheme $Hilb(X)$ consisting of smooth closed subvarieties of $X$. **Is this subset Zariski open in $Hilb(X)$?**

Comment: Yes. There is a universal subscheme $Z\subset X\times \mathrm{Hilb}(X)$, hence a proper map $Z\rightarrow \mathrm{Hilb}(X)$, and you are looking at the open subset of the base where the fiber is smooth.